# What could be the probable cause of my laptop sleeping while using?

Tags: laptop, sleep

While using it with external keyboard and mouse and keeping laptop over the table it works fine.

But as i take it in my laps and start to work it sleeps.(probably because of palm pressure i guess)

Checked my battery its fine since the issue happens also when I use laptop plugged in with charger.

Also it doesn't sleep when I close the lid.

Comment: What make and model of laptop?  Also, are you wearing any jewelry or similar (bracelet, watch, rings, etc.)?  Asking because some laptops have a magnetic sensor they use to know when the lid is closed (for example) that could be triggered by something you might wear.

Comment: No I am bare i dont wear anything.

Comment: Inspiron 15 3000 Series 3567

Comment: Is there anything else in your lap that might be magnetic?  Belt buckle, something in your pocket?  Potentially relevant links: https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/dell-inspiron-15-3000-series-3567-sleep-issue/td-p/6156644 and https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Dell-Inspiron-15-3000-series-Randomly-Goes-to-Sleep-Only-9-month/td-p/7336876

Comment: Since I'm home so casual outfit. No belt buckle or metal.